# How to use BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate and BeforeSaveEntityDelegate of web api context provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, breeze

```
[HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        try
        {

         EFContextProvider<ManagerContext> _contextProvider =
                           new EFContextProvider<ManagerContext>(); 
         _contextProvider.BeforeSaveEntityDelegate += BeforeSaveEntity();

         }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }

    }

    public bool BeforeSaveEntity(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
       //How do I use this
    }
```

I cannot understand how to use  `BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate` and `BeforeSaveEntityDelegate`. Please help me how to use such features. 
I have already visited the [this](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider#SaveInterception) site. But failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read this [link](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider) for getting more understanding of these delegates.

As per the tutorial on Breeze:

```
BeforeSaveEntity is called once for each entity before it is saved.
```

so you just need to supply you function to be executed before saving of each entity and Breeze EFContext provider will take care of executing this function once for each entity. If the function assigned to the delegate return false, it will abort the execution.